# Finding the values $a > 0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to use the fact that a series $b$ converges when $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\left\lvert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}\right\rvert < 1$

But now I need to find $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}$$

and this is where I'm stuck. Is there a way of evaluating this limit, or maybe another way of approaching the question without using the ratio test?

Comment: When it comes to expressions like $(n!)^{1/n}$, my go-to is usually Stirling's approximation to get an idea of what it is doing. Stirling is not precise by itself (it needs a tiny bit more explanation), but it is a good way to get a quick handle on more complicated factorial expressions.

Answer (score 3):

The series converges precisely for $a < 1$.

HINT:

On the one hand the inequality $n! < n^n$ holds, so the inequality $\sqrt[n]{n!} < \sqrt[n]{n^n} = n$, and in particular the inequality $\sqrt[n]{n!} < n$ holds. This implies the inequality $$\frac{a^n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} > \frac{a^n}{n}$$ holds. So this sum cannot converge for any $a \ge 1$.

On the other hand so does the inequality $n!>1=1^n$, so the inequality $\sqrt[n]{n!} > \sqrt[n]{1^n} =1$ holds. This implies the inequality $$\frac{a^n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}  < \frac{a^n}{1}=a^n$$ holds. So this sum must converge for any positive $a <1$.

**Note that Stirling's Inequality was not needed